# Creating an Open Extension for a Group seems case sensitive for GroupId

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I´m using **GraphExplorer** to create an **Open Extension** over a Group. I´m able to create the extension, but seems is "stored" using exact case on *GroupId*. I mean, if I **POST** to:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/C6AC8C0D-7669-4C00-BFF7-67A8CB37A7E6/extensions
```

The Open Extension is created, and I can see it doing **GET**:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/C6AC8C0D-7669-4C00-BFF7-67A8CB37A7E6/extensions
```

However, if I do the **GET** request with *GroupId* in lowercase, I don´t get my recently created extension:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/c6ac8c0d-7669-4c00-bff7-67a8cb37a7e6/extensions
```

I´ve tested it in 2 different tenants with same result, and I don´t see any mention to the "casing" thing in the Graph documentation. It seems a bug to me. Besides, is not just about the entire GroupId in Uppercase or lowercase, what it does is an exact mathing with the GroupId. When Getting the extensions, the groupId must be exactly the same casing as it was when you created the open extension.

Any thoughts from the Graph team would be really appreciate it.

Many thanks.

Comment: I see the same behavior. Weird but it is also weird you converted the object id to uppercase. Any insight on how you reached the scenario of having the resource id in uppercase?. Good practice is to treat resource ids as they are. Let me look in to thus further.

Comment: More than weird, I think is an issue. Nobody expects a case-sensitive behavior in a Guid value passed in a URL. In my scenario, I create a Group using Graph .net sdk and store the value in SQL (UniqueIdentifier field type). Later, I grab that value using EF Core, and do Entity.GroupId.ToString(). At that point, I get the guid as an Uppercase string value. Finally, using the Graph .net sdk I do: graphServiceClient?.Groups[groupId].Extensions.Request().AddAsync ....
The endpoint URL is passing the group id in uppercase.

Comment: In another module, I get the groupId using Graph SDK, filtering by mailNickName. Graph now returns the GroupId in lowercase, so if I check the /extensions, I don´t get the one created in previous point. Obviously, I can fix it easily always passing the GroupId in the same casing (or maybe the Graph .Net SDK should always do so when composing the endpoint), but to me the API is not consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. If the behaviour can be caused by the SDK and meaning you have not intentionally converted the id then this is definitely an issue.